# Manage processes/services in Linux from bash

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am doing a small project for university to compare 3 different Linux distros and their resource hits, as well as how they handle processes. I have been advised to use mainly bash rather than C++ or perl as the professor feels that this will result in a lower resource hit.

I am from a Java background mainly and of course am familiar with threads. What I want to know is, is it possible to assign a certain total memory for processes and to give each process a share of that memory and a priority? I want to emulate the situation of low memory and the need for non urgent processes to be killed or terminated when memory is low and for this all to be controlled as one of the options in my bash dialog box.
I know that this is all possible within Java as I did a project on that a few months back using the producer consumer example. Is it possible to do this within Linux servers? I am not using the GUI or desktop versions at all as the project forbids it.

I would also like to know if I can run a certain stress test at the same time as say, iostat and compare how it deals with stressed and non stressed results. Is it also possible to control this within bash?

Comment: many distros share basic OS kernels so comparisons between say ubuntu and debian where this is true would show relatively  few differences ... fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash gives you ability to automate anything you can execute yourself from the command line which is where you have access to all the tools you need to allocate memory, check memory usage, etc ... so yes go with bash - besides when using higher level languages they just make calls to same underlying OS managed datastructures through their own libraries ... you might be pleasantly surprised to discover how powerful command line utilities can be ... think of using bash as prototyping your approach quickly and if you discover you need complex data processing you may need to make calls to simple c binaries as need arises

.... here is a quick blip on intro to gnuplot

```
how to plot data from a file containing one vertical column of numbers :

from command line :

    gnuplot

    then at gnuplot> prompt :   plot "some-file-with-single-vertical-column"

to plot 3D data - IE.  frequency + offset + difference :


    To view tsv files (3 columns :  freq offset difference) use

    terminal :

    gnuplot

    splot 'freq_offset_diff_20130711_211554_pass_01.tsv' using 1:2:3 with points palette pointsize 3 pointtype 7
```

Comment: Is there anything else that would be worth stressing or gathering statistics for? I am already doing tests for CPU, memory, vmstat and iostat. I presume that the process control would be written within a separate bash script which is then referenced within the main dialog box as a function?

Comment: keep in mind you may want to include several servers when executing your stress testing - the hunters and the hunted

Comment: how do you mean? I will be running each one off of vmware player

Comment: when running in bound and out bound network connection stress tests it might be good to have two servers - one the hunted target generating out bound and receiving in bound connections from separate server(s) to separate out resource usage on the target

Comment: ok thanks, I will try that. Do you know how I can output the results of vmstat etc and stress tests on vmstat as graphs without downloading large software packages?

Comment: checkout gnuplot ... it handles command line and generates slick plotting with endless features ... cut  is extremely powerful to dice & slice arbitrary data just pipe it in and it cuts out data to be piped out into next downsteam step

Comment: I have installed it but it hasn't output any of the stats as graphs. for example in my file I have the following written for vmstat, where a user is able to input how long it will run for:                                                                   1) echo "process creation statistics";
vmstat $INT $CNT |tee /tmp/sar_proc_stat_$D                                                                                                  It is then written to a temp file after the statistics are displayed. would you know the syntax to put these stats into gnuplot?

Comment: you need to read up ... post any issues as new questions ... and mark up anyone who helps you with answers along the way - what comes around goes around

Comment: ok I have marked it and posted a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286509/stress-tests-on-linux-simultaneous-to-vmstat-iostat-output-on-gnu-plot-graph

Answer (score 1):

What I imagine you're looking for is cgroups.  You can set the maximum memory in bytes for the whole cgroup process group.

The other easy way is to make a new user put all the processes suid the user, and set a ulimit on the user

```
 luser hard as ?
```

inside of limits.conf

Comment: can the cgroups option be written in bash and then called as a function within a dialog box? can I give priority or importance to each process/service within cgroups?

Comment: cgget, cgset, and cgcreate can be used to set and get cgroup parameters

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups is a nice guide doing what seems to be the same thing as you want

Comment: I had written a few conf files already, e.g. temperature.conf. as shown below:                                                                                                                 /etc/init/proj_temperature.conf
/etc/init/proj_oxygen.conf
/etc/init/proj_humidity.conf

Output
/tmp/temperature.level
/tmp/oxygen.level
/tmp/humidity.level

Scripts
/tmp/temperature.sh
/tmp/oxygen.sh
/tmp/humidity.sh                                                                                                    Can these be controlled priority/memory wise within cgroups or is it completely separate?

Comment: cgexec will start a proces in a control group.  You can control the whole groups memory/priority from there, as well as modify an individual processes priority.

Comment: ok thanks. I am also trying to stress vmstat etc but I would like to have a stress test running simultaneously to vmstat, which I will write in bash. do you know the syntax of this? When I run a normal stress test, it just goes for one second, whereas I want an output like vmstat 1 50 for example, but with a spike.